# The MSO review page still refers to "Stack Exchange Meta"

Tags: bug, status-completed, mso-mse-split, review-queues

A nitpick, certainly, but the [review page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/review) here on MSO refers to the site as "Stack Exchange Meta":

[image]

Seems like it should instead say "Meta Stack Overflow" now.